# How to click Element which is having class same as other element in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm working on python based selenium automation testing and I'm new to this tech.I need to click Activity Report from the below code.

```
 <a href="../reports/ActivityReport.aspx">
 <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 menu-button">Activity Report</div>
 </a> ---
```

Same class name

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 menu-button">Reports</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 menu-button">Activity Report</div>
```

While trying to click it i'm facing this problem.Pls give me a solution.
Thanks in advance.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/test1/T1.py", line 21, in <module>
     driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#form1 > div:nth-child(3) > 
     div.row 
     > div > a:nth-child(2) > div').click()
  File "C:\Python36\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in 
    click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
   File "C:\Python36\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, 
   in _execute
   return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Python36\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in 
   execute
   self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python36\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, 
    in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Comment: Add a bigger excerpt of the HTML - the locator you used looks quite deep, `form1 > div:nth-child(3) > div.row > div > a:nth-child(2) > div`, there's more to that. Alternatively, look at @Pooja 's solution - his xpath locates the element by its text (one of the many benefits of xpath over css).

Answer (score 0):

Below given snippet should most definitely work for you:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 menu-button'][contains(text(),'Activity R')]")
```

If above does not work, below should also do:

```
lst_menu = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 menu-button']")
for item in lst_menu:
    if (item.get_attribute("text") == 'Activity Report'):
        item.click()
```

Comment: still i'm getting same kind of error.pls help me on this...all other things are done.because of this one line my work got stuck

Comment: No bro.same error.i asked dev team to add a ID there...but problem not solved

Answer (score 0):

try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Activity Report')]")
```

or more radical

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-sm-2') and contains(@class ,'col-md-2') and contains(@class ,'col-lg-2') and contains(@class, 'menu-button') and contains(text(), 'Activity Report')]")
```

Comment: Thanks bro..still not fixed.

Comment: You can try install some chrome extension like ChroPath or simialr to check if xpath is valid for the page... if none works from above that can mean that element is not visible or accessible by webdriver.

Comment: Okay bro..Thanks..will check it